# Проблема с многопроцессорностью Python

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing

Возникла проблема,которая сильно меня гложет,не могу разобраться с ней уже продолжительное количество времени. Обрисую ситуацию: Имеется класс `File`, который состоит из нескольких методов,которые в свою очередь выполняют свойственные им операции над переданным им файлом (путем к файлу). 
Мне необходимо сделать так,что бы параллельно создавались несколько экземпляров класса и далее совершить над ними какое-либо действие(для простоты просто вернуть через этот экземпляр поле класса). При запуске скрипта он может один раз вывести то,что от него требуется,а если еще раз запустить этот скрипт,ничего не изменяя,то постоянно выдает ошибку(которую я опишу ниже). 
Строки,которые передаются функции `Triplex` абсолютно адекватные,без каких-либо ошибок в синтаксисе. Если пытаться передавать функции `Triplex` строку в виде Triplex(mas[0]),то код выдает то,что от него требуется. Помогите понять ошибку! Спасибо.

### КОД

```
import magic
import os
import hashlib
import zlib
import stat
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

class File:
    Hash_md5 = None
    Hash_sha256 = None
    Hash_crc32 = None
    Name = None
    Path = None
    Size = None
    Type_signature = None
    Type_extension = None
    Executive = None
    def __init__(self,path):
        File.Hash_md5 = self.Hash_md5(path)
        File.Hash_sha256 = self.Hash_sha256(path)
        File.Hash_crc32 = self.Hash_crc32(path)
        File.Name = self.Name(path)
        File.Path = self.Path(path)
        File.Size = self.Size(path)
        File.Type_signature = self.Type_signature(path)
        File.Type_extension = self.Type_extension(path)
        File.Executive = self.Executive(path)
        return None

    def Hash_md5(self,path):
        with open(path, 'rb') as file:
            obj = hashlib.md5()
            while True:
                data = file.read(8192)
                if not data:
                    break
                obj.update(data)
        return obj.hexdigest()

    def Hash_sha256(self,path):
        with open(path, 'rb') as file:
            obj = hashlib.sha256()
            while True:
                data = file.read(8192)
                if not data:
                    break
                obj.update(data)
        return obj.hexdigest()

    def Hash_crc32(self,path):
        prev = 0
        for eachLine in open(path,"rb"):
            prev = zlib.crc32(eachLine, prev)
        return "%X"%(prev & 0xFFFFFFFF)

    def Name(self,path):
        start = path.rfind("/")
        return path[start+1:]

    def Path(self,path):
        return path

    def Size(self,path):
        return os.path.getsize(path) #bytes

    def Type_signature(self,path):
        return magic.from_file(path)

    def Type_extension(self,path):
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(path)
        return file_extension

    def Executive(self,path):
        st = os.stat(path)
        return bool(st.st_mode & stat.S_IXUSR)  


def triplex(param):
    obj0 = File(param)
    return obj0.Size

obj = Pool()
mas = ["/root/Downloads/eltekh.pdf","/root/Downloads/control.tar.gz","/root/Downloads/bootstrap-4.1.3-dist.zip","/root/Downloads/templates","/root/Downloads/mysql-connector-python-8.0.12.zip"]
result = obj.map(triplex, mas)
print(result)
```

### ОШИБКА

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "main_file.py", line 92, in triplex
    obj0 = File(param)
  File "main_file.py", line 20, in __init__
    File.Hash_md5 = self.Hash_md5(path)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_file.py", line 100, in <module>
    result = obj.map(triplex, mas)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 288, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 670, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Если в списке `mas` оставить меньше элементов,например,первые 3,тогда программа выполняется,как нужно всегда. Если передавать 4 аргумента,то программа начинает выполняться через раз(то есть при первом запуске - все гуд,при втором вылетает ошибка,при третьем снова ошибка,при четвертом - все гуд и тд)

Comment: с «многопроцессорностью» проблема, в первом приближении, ни как не связана, сам класс написан достаточно абсурдно, в частности вот эта строка (и все остальные подобные): `File.Hash_md5 = self.Hash_md5(path)`; что по твоему должна делать?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, Эти строки в конструкторе вызывают методы класса и присваивают полям класса соответствующие значения вывода методов. Это нужно,что бы при обращении к экземпляру класса можно было написать obj.Size или obj.Hash_md5 и получить значения. Даже,если учитывать,что класс написан абсурдно,то как объяснить,что при 3х значениях в списке `mas` все работает отлично и выводит,то,что требуется,а при 5 значениях вылетают ошибки?

Comment: Мне кажется, вам хотят указать на то, что File.Hash_md5 это обращение к статическому члену класса, который общий на все экземпляры.

Comment: @MartinOrlov, а вот в том, что всё падает только после третьего файла, а не на втором уже виновата гонка в состоянии многопоточности=) при однопоточном исполнении оно будет всегда падать на втором...

Comment: @Fat-Zer , Mike, то есть проблема может быть в том,что процессы,выполняясь параллельно меняют общий для всех процессов статистический член класса и ,соответсвенно,когда один из подпроцессов хочет обратиться к этому общему члену(то есть изменить его значение),другой(подпроцесс) может заниматься эим же самым,то есть изменять "константу"?

Comment: @Mike, всё намного хуже, я не настолько хорошо знаю питон, чтобы описать насколько это плохо в корректных терминах, но говоря кухонным языком `File.Hash_md5` является так же и методом объекта и это присваивание заменяет метод на строку, причём делает это для всех экземпляров класса.

Comment: @MartinOrlov, да в этом тоже проблема, и здесь была бы нужна синхронизация, но (а) скорей всего это ошибка и стоит сделать эти пременные членами экземпляра, а не класса и (б) это меньшая проблема (см. предыдущий комментарий), надо или использовать разные имена, или использовать какую-то более тёмную питонью магию, чем я могу вспомнить/придумать на вскидку...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Вот теперь я понял, почему ошибка гласит что пытаются выполнить строку :) Однако такая простая замена методов в классе это удобно, мне уже начинает нравится этот язык :) Неудобно только, что объявление одноименного метода после объявления поля не приводит к ошибке синтаксиса.